# Airflow - task level end_date not working

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am testing `end_date` parameter at a task_level, but seems like once one task's `end_date` is satisfied the other tasks also stop. Below is a code example:

```
default_args = {'owner': 'xyz', 'depends_on_past': False,}

with DAG('dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily', catchup=True) as dag:
    bash_end = BashOperator(
        task_id='bash_end',
        bash_command='echo {{ ds }}',
        start_date=datetime(2020, 3, 1),
        end_date=datetime(2020, 3, 5)
    )

    bash_no_end = BashOperator(
        task_id='bash_no_end',
        bash_command='echo {{ ds }}',
        start_date=datetime(2020, 3, 3),
    )
```

In above example, `start_date` works perfectly, but after 2020-03-05 even `bash_no_end` doesn't get scheduled. Is this behaviour expected?